# grails createLink throws error only when deploying on a server

Tags: apache, tomcat, grails

grails version: 3.1.1
groovy version: 2.4.5
jvm version: 1.8.0_25
Apache Tomcat: 7.0.70

So i have this in my main view to navigate:

```
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Test Your Data<span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li><a href="${createLink(controller:'testdata', action:'location')}">GIS Data</a></li>
<li><a href="${createLink(controller:'testdata', action:'credit')}">Credit Data</a></li>
<li><a href="${createLink(controller:'testdata', action:'vehicle')}">Axiom Data</a></li>
<li><a href="${createLink(controller:'testdata', action:'license')}">MVR Data</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Add New Data<span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li><a href="${createLink(controller:'UploadTestData', action:'uploadLocation')}">Location Data</a></li>
<li><a href="${createLink(controller:'UploadTestData', action:'uploadCredit')}">Credit Data</a></li>
<li><a href="${createLink(controller:'UploadTestData', action:'uploadVehicle')}">Vehicle Data</a></li>
<li><a href="${createLink(controller:'UploadTestData', action:'uploadLicense')}">Licence Data</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
```

It works when i run it on my local in dev and prod but when i build a war and put it on the server all the createlinks in UploadTestData do not work and throw this error:
javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name '/uploadTestData/uploadGis' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet'

Comment: Try to change to absolute path - ${createLink(controller:'UploadTestData', action:'uploadLocation', absolute:true)}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `<g:link> </g:link>` which provided by the grails

E.g

```
 <li><g:link resource="testdata" action="location">GIS Data</g:link></li>
```

resource = your controller name.

action   = your controller action name.

For more Details :

http://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Tags/link.html